# How to add a new domain to an existing single site WordPress server?

Tags: multisite

I'm running a single site WP installation on my little server that hosts  `example.com`, how do I add to the same server `example2.com`?

I know the first thing to do will be do go [from single site to multi site](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/moving-wordpress-site-into-multisite/). Then will I be able to host on the WP network two different sites with nothing in common, i.e. different domain?

Will I need a multiple databases too?

Answer (score 0):

With WP Multisite, you will have a network of any number of domains. Sites in Multisite can have common plugins and themes. However, different set of plugins can be activated on each site, as well as different themes can be used.

Sites in Multisite network always have one common database. This allows to switch between sites in php code and get an information from another site in the network, if it is needed.